# Is it possible to fwrite() raw data to standard output?

Tags: c, file, struct, io, stdout

Assume I have a struct called "Book", after constructing several "Books" I want to print the raw data of them to standard output. I can't think of any ways to do it using `printf` so I wonder can I use `fwrite` to read a "Book" and write it to standard output?

I tried something like the following but didn't work:

Comment: Why are you specifying the length as `sizeof(head->p)`, if your intent is to write out `head->Book`?

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean, then?

Comment: `fwrite(Address of Object, Size of data, Number of element, Stream)`

Answer (score 0):

You *can* write it to stdout, but it will not be formatted in a human-readable manner - it will just be the binary values that happened to be in the structure fields (and padding bytes). If you want something human readable, use `printf` on the fields of the struct.

It's rarely a good idea to `fwrite` structs, even when you do want binary data. For one, there's no portable way of reading them back, as structure layout may depend on the platform, and you may also leak sensitive information, as the padding bytes and parts of arrays that you haven't written etc. may contain leftover information from other parts of your program. Either write the fields explicitly by yourself, or use one of the many serialization libraries available instead.